# R cannot be resolved to a variable, rebuilding doesn't solve

Tags: android, r.java-file

Can someone help me?

```
public class Maths4to5Home extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
    {
        private Button button_4to5PlayGame, button_mathsInstructions, button_4to5Scores;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maths4to5home); //error

            button_4to5PlayGame = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_4to5PlayGame); //error
            button_mathsInstructions = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_mathsInstructions); //error
            button_4to5Scores = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_4to5Scores); //error
```

I have included a sample of code above and highlighted where my errors are. I am  being constantly told that `R` cannot be resolved to a variable. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding. Also I have tried importing `R` (as the quick fix suggests) but then I am told that for example in my `setContentView()` that

```
activity_maths4to5home cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check out for subtle errors in your xml files. Also check that you didn't use invalid chars in file names, such as `-` or capital letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the correct `R` — specifically, the one for your project. This is based on what's in your project's manifest. If your manifest declares the project's package to be `com.example.my_project` then you need to `import com.example.my_project.R;`.

If your activity is already in the project's package, then you do not need to import `R`. However, you specifically need to **not** import `android.R`.

The error message may also be caused by a missing R.java. This can happen if errors in your resources prevents R.java from being generated. You should check that there are no errors in any of your resource files.

Comment: Hi Ted. I tried that but now getting the message "The import com.example.develappment.R cannot be resolved".

Comment: @user3578463 - I suspected that might be an issue and was adding a bit to my answer about that. Check for errors in your resources (also for typos in the package name). If you're using Eclipse, check whether there's a `gen/` folder inside your project folder and that it contains the required R.java file.

Comment: Again, I tried that and I have no errors in my resource folder. I am totally at a loss here :( There is a gen/ folder and it does not have the R.java file.

Comment: @user3578463 - Look in the Problems view (Window > Show View > Problems). There may be resource file errors showing up there that wouldn't show up in the package explorer view.

Comment: @user3578463 - Also (if you're using Eclipse) try right-clicking on the project in Package Explorer and selecting Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

Comment: I made a typo in my last comment, there is no R.java file in my gen/ folder.

Comment: @user3578463 - Well, that's where your problem lies; not in your code. You need to track down why R.java is not being generated.

Comment: Have you any suggestions of how I go about that? Sorry to pester you again

Comment: @user3578463 - If nothing shows up in the Problems view, check the Android console for errors when you clean and rebuild. Try running aapt manually. Try opening each .xml file, making a "non-change change" (e.g., add and delete a blank) and save. (Make sure you have Build Automatically enabled in the Project menu.) This will force the aapt to recompile that file and highlight any errors it may have. If all else fails, copy all the resource files to a backup location, delete them from your project, and add them back in one at a time, cleaning and rebuilding, until R.java fails to generate.

Comment: Copying the files to a backup location, deleting them from the project, and re-adding them worked. Thanks Ted Hopp!